# How should I build the architecture of my Angular webapp, one module per element or one module grouping together all the different elements?

Tags: angular, architecture

I'm creating an Angular web application, my first! I'm wondering about the architecture of my app.
To give you some context :
It's a web app for a school's student office, the different pages are

- Home page
- Office
- Clubs
- partners
- Membership
- Lost card
- Events

You can add items to this site from an administrator account, such as news on the home page, members of the board on the offices page, and clubs and partners on their respective pages.

All these elements have several attributes in common but are all slightly different.

They are :

- partners

  - id
  - Name
  - url
  - details
  - logo
- clubs

  - id
  - Name
  - url
  - details
  - logo
- news

  - id
  - Title
  - date
  - details
  - image
- member

  - id
  - first name
  - last name
  - date of birth
  - mail
  - phone
  - school year
  - speciality
  - picture
- councilMember

  - id
  - fist name
  - second name
  - url
  - picture

The question I have is this:

Is it wiser to create an element.ts class with a base common to all the elements and then child elements inheriting from this class and therefore a form and an associated service with several cases (if) to specialise the form/service depending on the object inheriting from the element we're dealing with? Or to create a class for each element and a form and service for each element you want to create.

I don't know which is the best practice to adopt.